# Same observation in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
 ID1     ID2    variables
  a      b        something
  b      g        something
  c      h        something
  d      i        something
  a      h        something
```

If an ID shows up in both ID1 and ID2 I want the observation of this value in ID1 to be excluded from the dataset.
So in this case

```
 ID1     ID2    variables
  a      b        something       
  c      h        something
  d      i        something
  a      h        something
```

What I considered:

There can be multiple observations of the same ID. Renaming, concatenating and dropping duplicates will not work.

The dataset is rather large (millions of observations), so loops for each value are not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if ID1 has [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) values from `ID2` and drop them by using [`.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) slicing to filter data.

```
In [76]: df.loc[~df['ID1'].isin(df['ID2']), :]
Out[76]:
  ID1 ID2  variables
0   a   b  something
2   c   h  something
3   d   i  something
4   a   h  something
```

Details:

```
In [77]: df
Out[77]:
  ID1 ID2  variables
0   a   b  something
1   b   g  something
2   c   h  something
3   d   i  something
4   a   h  something

In [78]: ~df['ID1'].isin(df['ID2'])
Out[78]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
Name: ID1, dtype: bool

In [79]: df.loc[~df['ID1'].isin(df['ID2']), :]
Out[79]:
  ID1 ID2  variables
0   a   b  something
2   c   h  something
3   d   i  something
4   a   h  something
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with inverting boolean `Series` by `~` with [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print df.ID1.isin(df.ID2)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False

print ~df.ID1.isin(df.ID2)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
Name: ID1, dtype: bool

print df[~df.ID1.isin(df.ID2)]
  ID1 ID2  variables
0   a   b  something
2   c   h  something
3   d   i  something
4   a   h  something
```

**TESTING**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [157]: %timeit df.loc[~df['ID1'].isin(df['ID2']), :]
10 loops, best of 3: 55.5 ms per loop

In [158]: %timeit df[~df.ID1.isin(df.ID2)]
10 loops, best of 3: 55 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way maybe

```
df.query('ID1 not in ID2')
```